# Clone Input and validation in MVC 3 by jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, unobtrusive-validation

I use MVC3 model Validation and Unobtrusive for show validation
and try to find some way to clone element and validation.

This is My View Code:

```
<div id="d1" class="Addable">
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CellPhone)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CellPhone)
</div>
<input type"button" class="AddE" />
```

And HTML Dom is:

```
<div class="Addable" id="d1">
  <input type="text" value="" name="CellPhone" id="CellPhone" data-val-required="Req."
   data-val-regex-pattern="^04[1234][0-9]{6}$" data-val-regex="notValid" data-val="true"
   class="text-box single-line valid">

 <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="CellPhone" 
  class="invalid-side-note field-validation-valid"></span>
</div>
```

So I use the following script to clone new one with change names like array names:

```
//Add new Addable div
$('.AddNewE').click(function () {

    var Target = $('.Addable:first');
    var TargetId = $(Target).attr('id');
    var Count = $('.Addable#' + TargetId).size();
    var CloneTarget = $(Target).clone();
    CloneTarget.find('input').val('');
    CloneTarget.insertAfter('.Addable:last');
    var TargetName = $(Target).find('input').attr('name');

    if (Count == 1) {

        var CloneName = TargetName + '[1]';
        TargetName = TargetName + '[0]';

        $(Target).find('input').attr('name', TargetName);
        $(Target).find('span[class|="field-validation"]').attr('data-valmsg-for', TargetName);

        $(CloneTarget).find('input').attr('name', CloneName);
        $(CloneTarget).find('span[class|="field-validation"]').attr('data-valmsg-for', CloneName);

    } else {

        var indx = TargetName.length - 3;
        var CloneTargetName = TargetName.substring(0, indx);
        CloneTargetName = CloneTargetName + '[' + Count + ']';
        $(CloneTarget).find('input').attr('name', CloneTargetName);
        $(CloneTarget).find('span[class|="field-validation"]').attr('data-valmsg-for', CloneTargetName);
    }

});
```

After first clone the Dom is:

```
<div class="Addable" id="d1">
  <input type="text" value="" name="CellPhone[0]" id="CellPhone" data-val-required="Req."
   data-val-regex-pattern="^04[1234][0-9]{6}$" data-val-regex="notValid" data-val="true"
   class="text-box single-line valid">

 <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="CellPhone[0]" 
  class="invalid-side-note field-validation-valid"></span>
</div>


<div class="Addable" id="d1">
  <input type="text" value="" name="CellPhone[1]" id="CellPhone" data-val-required="Req."
   data-val-regex-pattern="^04[1234][0-9]{6}$" data-val-regex="notValid" data-val="true"
   class="text-box single-line valid">

 <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="CellPhone[1]" 
  class="invalid-side-note field-validation-valid"></span>
</div>
```

I change both validation span and input because every input will have own validation. 
but after clone the validation not worked at all. where is the problem? what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This lines help me:

```js
$('form').removeData('validator');
$('form').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');
```